# No puedo ejecutar un programa en javaScript que carga unas imágenes

Tags: javascript, imagen, canvas, google-sites

Hice un programa en JavaScript que pone un fondo y unas imágenes en el canvas que luego se deben mover con el ratón. En mi computador el programa funciona correctamente pero cuando subo el código a Google sites y los archivos de las imágenes el programa no muestra ni el fondo ni las imágenes. Parece que hay un problema con un permiso para iniciar una presentación.
Aparece el siguiente error:

This is a new flag for `<iframe sandbox="...">` which will
allow embedders to have control over whether an iframe can start a presentation session.

Gracias

Comment: [No es un error](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5462833647058944).

Answer (score 0):

el error que estás experimentando parece estar relacionado con la política de seguridad de Google Sites que restringe ciertas características de iframes, como las presentaciones, que pueden ser utilizadas para controlar la pantalla o el contenido del navegador.
Te recomiendo que verifiques los permiosos y que revises las políticas de iframe de Google Sites.